# Binding of DiscreteStringKeyFrame does not work

Tags: wpf, animation, binding, resources, storyboard

I have a Storyboard with StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames:

```
<Storyboard> 
    <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.ToolTip)" Storyboard.TargetName="xButton">
        <DiscreteStringKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding State,Converter={StaticResource StateToStringConverter},StringFormat={x:Static props:Resources.xToolTipText}}"/>
    </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    ....
<Storyboard>
```

xToolTipText comes from Resources:

```
Press ({0} State)
```

The value received for resources is variable State (int) from Model.

The whole thing can not work because binding of DiscreteStringKeyFrame does not work (I think the reason is that he does not belong to the visual tree).

Which is another way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `proxy binding` as this post:

**[How to bind to data when the DataContext is not inherited](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/)**

And it worked.